# Can multiple independent applications using Redisson share same clustered Redis?

Tags: redis, shared-memory, redisson

So I would like to ask if there will be any contention issues due to shared access to the same `Redis` cluster by multiple separate applications which use `Redisson` library (each application in turn has several instances of themselves).

Does `Redisson` library support such use case? Or do I need to configure `Redisson` in each application, for example add some kind of prefix or app name (as it is possible with `Quartz` where you can define `prefixes for tables` used by separate applications having access to the same `db` and using `Quartz` independently).

Won't the tasks submitted to `ExecutorService` in one app be forwarded to completely another application which also uses `Redisson` and not to another instance of the same application?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend you to use prefix/suffix in Redisson's object names when you share same Redis setup in cluster mode across multiple independent applications.